# Isn't it obvious that there is life outside earth?

Tags: life, existence-of-god

Earth is a tiny speck in the Universe.
Suppose God created life on earth.
Isn't it obvious that there is life outside earth ?
I mean, who will create such a vast universe and then such a fantastic thing (life) only in one tiny speck in that !

Comment: Maybe "obvious"... but we haven't still empirical verification of it.

Comment: Let's say yes. So?

Comment: As you have presented it there is no philosophical issue to your question. The Drake Equation attempts to use the information we have to get a picture of how like we are to see alien life. The Fermi Paradox is the topic of why we don't see any. When you put figures on likelihoods, & our current limited observations, it's far from expected that we would have seen aliens yet

Comment: The Drake equation is based on no information; it is pure speculation.

Comment: @DavidGudeman: Drake presented it not for purposes of quantifying the number of alien civilisations, but as a way to stimulate scientific dialogue at the first scientific meeting on the search for extraterrestrial intelligence. It is highly conjectural, & because of compound errors cannot be used to draw firm conclusions. That doesn't make it not useful, & it is science. It is continuously being refined, as data improves. Cosmology is full of huge error bars, but thinking quantatively at scale is still profoundly useful.

Comment: What a strange question. Why would you start by supposing that God exists? Which God? The God of Classical Theism? According to classical theism, God is all powerful, so can do anything he wants. So what issue is there with God creating life in just one place? Still, the question is irrelevant as such a God doesn't exist...

Comment: @CriglCragl, I don't understand how your response is responsive to what I said. You said the Drake equation is based on information; I objected that it is not, and you admit now that it was "highly conjectural". None of the other stuff you said seems to be relevant to what I said.

Comment: @DavidGudeman: Conjectural doesn't mean no information. We are pretty sure abiogenesis occurred on Earth, we know it involved liquid water, & certain chemical reactions to be possible. Sure don't overstate the accuracy /reliability, & having only 1 data point to calculate probability of life even given exactly the same conditions isn't enough, & radically different types of abiogenesis are total unknowns. But we have the example of Earth, & that is information.

Comment: When calculating probabilities, one data point is essentially no information.

Answer (score 1):

The **Kopernikus** principle requests: Do not consider the location of yourself a distinguished place in the world:

Neither the earth, the sun, the milky way, nor our local group etc. are the center of the known universe. As far as we can investigate the universe, we do not find a center or a distinguished point.

Of course one cannot prove the Kopernikus principle. But it is a useful heuristic. Because it has always extended the scope of our view. Following the Kopernikus principle I prefer the hypothesis of the existence of many stars with planets, many planets with living beings, and many species of living beings which developed intelligence.

The value of the hypothesis about the existence of God is debated. My answer is „Yes“ to your question

„Isn't it obvious that there is life outside earth?“

but I do not invoke the God-hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

It's **very** obvious. It's reasonable to assume that the situations in evolving planetary systems with a Sun-like are similar to ours.

There are billions Sun-like stars and there is no reason to assume they have no planets or different ingredients. So around virtually every Sun-like star life has evolved and the chance is high that people can be found in the whole universe. Life is inevitable.